# how to draw oval shape around objects in image

Tags: matlab, matlab-figure

I want to draw oval shape around cells in a binary image. So far I tried the code shown below to draw ellipses around cells in a binary image. In code, IBord is the binary image.Code draws ellipse shape successfully around cells.

```
s = regionprops(IBord, 'Orientation', 'MajorAxisLength', 'MinorAxisLength',    'Eccentricity', 'Centroid');
figure(2);
imshow(IBord)


phi = linspace(0,2*pi,50);
cosphi = cos(phi);
sinphi = sin(phi);

for k = 1:length(s)
xbar = s(k).Centroid(1);
ybar = s(k).Centroid(2);

a = s(k).MajorAxisLength/2;
b = s(k).MinorAxisLength/2;


theta = pi*s(k).Orientation/180;
R = [ cos(theta)   sin(theta)
     -sin(theta)   cos(theta)];


xy = [a*cosphi;b*sinphi];
xy = R*xy;

X = xy(1,:) + xbar;
Y = xy(2,:) + ybar;

plot(X,Y,'r','LineWidth',2);

end
```

kindly suggest how can i modify this code to draw oval shape (egg like shape) around cells in a binary image.

Comment: Try to use egg-functions, like as here for example: http://www.mathematische-basteleien.de/eggcurves.htm   or here:  http://www.geocities.jp/nyjp07/Egg/index_egg_E.html

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way to achieve this effect is to use smaller exponents on `cosphi` and `sinphi`.

```
gam = .8
xy = [a * sign(cosphi) .* abs(cosphi).^gam;  b * sign(sinphi) .* abs(sinphi).^gam];
```

Play around with `gam`.  This should give more oval-ly shapes.

Comment: Actually i want this kind of shape http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/f/f3/Oval1.svg/2000px-Oval1.svg.png